# Get tree of single item in MySQL hierachircal database

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I want to retrieve the path to a single node in a hierachical database where only the parent node ID is stored as a reference. Could someone give me a query or some advice on how to write a query (ideally the first option - I'm a MySQL noob) so that all the node titles in the end node's path are given in a generated table?

```
id   name          depth
10   Top level     0
22   Second level  1
34   3rd level     2
43   End node      3
```

I want to use this data to create on of those "you are here" lists like:

`Home > Forums > Stuffs > ... > Topics`

Thanks for any help,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible for a fixed number of levels, as there is no recursion in SQL.

You can convert your data structure from the ["adjacency list" model you have to the so-called "nested sets" model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). With that model a "find the path to the top" query is possible.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried using a couple of different models to no avail. I've managed to fix it with a PHP function. It's not ideal but it works. I'll look into fixing it at a later date.